# jQuery Ajax - Wrong response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem with jQuery ajax function:

```
var arrayIdEq = JSON.stringify(iditem);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",   
        url: "index.php",
        dataType : 'text', 
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {
            arrayIdEq : arrayIdEq
        },
        success: function(answer) {
            alert(answer);
        },
        complete: function() {
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, errorText, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR+" - "+errorText+" - "+errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

"arrayIdEq" contains number from 0 to 7, or string "EMPTY".
PHP code:

```
elseif(isset($_POST['arrayIdEq'])){ 
$answer = "my_answer";
return $answer;
```

After request, when success response come, alert show up... but here's the problem. Instead of "$answer" value, alert contains... HTML code from my main page!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title> Medivia</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Medivia</h1>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <label>E-mail:<br><input type="text" name="mail" required></label>
    <br>
    <label>Hasło:<br><input type="password" name="pass" required></label>
    <br>
    <button name="login">Zaloguj się</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea what happend here. Could anybody explain to me what happend there? What did i do wrong?

Comment: You are posting your ajax request to: `index.php`. If that's not where you have your PHP-code, then it will simply return that page.

Comment: Do you ever output `$answer` in your PHP?

Comment: @chris85 I do not.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson But index.php it's place where i exactly keep my php code.

Comment: @Petrus That is your issue. The AJAX receives what you output on the page you send the request to.

Comment: You should look at jeroens answer.

Comment: @chris85 Ok, i replaced "return" with "echo". Still the same result :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `answer` variable in the `success` function will contain the complete output of your php script.

So when you call `index.php` and you do:

```
elseif(isset($_POST['arrayIdEq'])){ 
  $answer = "my_answer";
  return $answer;
}
```

The script will only exit if the `return` statement is called from the main script (not from within a function) but the output will be the output generated by the script until that point.

Your script should output - and not `return` - only what you want returned to the javascript.

Probably a separate script for ajax requests will be a more convenient solution than using the `index.php` file you use to build the complete page.

Comment: I replaced "return" with "echo". But result is the same as before.

Comment: @Petrus The script only has `<?php echo 'something'; ?>` in it?

Comment: @chris85 yea, and it works! :) Sorry for the mess guys, english is not my native language. Still a lot to learn. Thanks for the help!